# Connect through OpenVPN to VPN - network disconnects

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn, vpn

When I connect using openvpn 'my-config-file.ovpn' (client) the network disconnects, I'm using a non gui ubuntu so there's no network manager with a gui. I do all in shell, I heard to read on splitrouting, policy routing, but they're a bit too advanced for me and I don't know if these are my issues, either way I tried routing, and did the following in terminal:

```
ip rule add from myip table 10
ip route add default via mygatewayip table 10
```

I suppose I wouldn't have this problem if I had a gui, but in this case I don't.

but did not work, with that the network is actually up for a while but I cannot ping to any domain, but I'm connected to the server. Any help?

Comment: Does the same config work on any other devices?

Comment: Can you detail a bit about "network disconnects"? You are no longer able to access local subnets? You are no longer able to access hosts in you own subnet? You are no longer able to acces the internet? Are you able to access remote hosts over VPN? I'm thinking about an overlap of the routes pushed by your VPN server with your local subnets. Also, the output of `ip ro sh` and some more details about you subnets and routing would help.

Comment: The config is from the vpn provider with the server ip I want to connect to, no it doesn't work on any other device, and it's default, it's a server I connect to so the whole network of the server that has the openvpn client disconnects, I cannot even ping the server. So I have to reinstall the server from my control panel and then boot it again.

Comment: So, you are connecting from your PC to a VPS, over internet, and you start your VPN client on that VPS, to connect to some Open VPN server. Right? If that's the case, and your Open VPN server pushes a default route, it's normal for you to be unable to access your VPS over internet as your traffic will be routed asymmetrical (your VPS receives traffic over the public IP and replies over VPN). Before connecting the VPN client, try adding a route on your VPS to your PCs public address, something like `ip ro a mypcpublicip/32 via mygatewayip`.

Comment: Ok I did what you wrote, now the connection is alive to my PC, but my server with the client that has openvpn cannot connect to any domains but only ips? The connection has been alive for a few minutes now, no problems. Ok I reconnected to the server with the client and now I can connect to domains from the server, but seems like the vpn is not active at all now on the server as I checked the ip of it.

Comment: @S.L That's a resolving issues. Check `/etc/resolv.conf`. Can you `ping` the nameservers listed there? If not, can you `ping 8.8.8.8`? If yes, add 8.8.8.8, as your first nameserver in `/etc/resolve.conf`.

Comment: Yes, I can ping the nameserver ip in /etc/resolv.conf and I can ping 8.8.8.8 aswell.

Comment: This is what my route -n list looks like if it helps: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b04d0532c355e375a36c4d6c8d5ba02d

Comment: Ok, I did add 8.8.8.8 to my /etc/resolv.conf even though I could ping the nameserver I already had in there, and it solved my problem! Adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 solved the problem now I can connect to any ip or domain. Probably this had something to do with the old nameserver from the ISP interfering with the VPN and then breaks it, as I had read on openvpn's irc channel but with changed nameserver, it doesn't. Thanks for your input and help. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Finally Solved! By using the above rules/routes and changing the nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf to 8.8.8.8 as the old one did interfere with the VPN's connection.